# How to set servicePort equal to the randomly generated hostPort?

Tags: mesos, marathon, dcos

I see that setting the boolean requirePorts in the marathon app JSON will set the containerPort equal to the hostPort, but I need the opposite scenario - I set hostPort to 0 and now want the servicePort (I'm using marathon-lb) to be equal to the generated hostPort number.

I tried using the automatic environment variable $HOST0 for example but it would accept this in the servicePort field.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the app.json?

Comment: You can use HOST network instead of BRIDGE. Then you will have same random port on container as on host. I'm not sure if I get you question can you add an example?

Comment: Nevermind, I couldnt set it to HOST network and had to use BRIDGE. I found a workaround to do what I wanted such that in the end this question didnt matter. If this was possible then it would have made my life easier though.